GPyOpt - how to specify "maxiter" for OptLbfgs while using "suggest_next_locations"?
I have a following code using GPyOpt's "suggest_next_locations" to perform Bayesian optimization for one cycle. I would like to use an increased "maxiter" for OptLbfgs, as the default value does not seem to be sufficient for my problem. How can I change "maxiter"?
import GPyOpt

bo = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(
    f=my_objective_func,
    domain=my_domain,
    X=init_x,
    Y=init_y,
    **other_params,
)

new_x = bo.suggest_next_locations(ignored_X=self._x)
new_y = my_objective_func(new_x)

I like to know how to specify "maxiter" while using "suggest_next_locations". I am reluctant to use "run_optimization" for some reason.
